# Can I download a file in parts? [Chrome]

Tags: google-chrome, internet, download, download-manager

I want to download a 5 GB of file but according to my internet plan only 2 GB of high speed data comes per day. So, The question is "How can i download it in parts."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Chrome's download manager "pause" feature really work?](https://superuser.com/questions/332910/does-chromes-download-manager-pause-feature-really-work)

Comment: I don't use Chrome often enough to be sure, but there are lots of external down-load managers that will do it for you. I have successfully used [DAP](http://www.speedbit.com/) in the past, before I switched to Linux. Whatever OS you're on, I am sure you'll find one if Chrome doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Any other software like DAP. @AFH

Comment: You can use [this site](http://alternativeto.net/) to find alternatives for Linux, Mac and Windows systems.

Comment: DAP worked awesome! Thx @AFH

Comment: I've summarised my comments in an answer, so that others can see that your question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't do what you want with Chrome's internal down-loader, you can always use an external down-load manager.

I have always found [Download Accelerator Plus](http://www.speedbit.com/) works very well in Windows, but there are plenty of others to choose from, not only for Windows, but Linux and Mac as well.

You didn't say what OS you're using: [this site](http://alternativeto.net/) is a good place to find alternative software for Windows, Linux and Mac, including freeware.